# Find rss links in a webpage using regex

Tags: python, regex, rss

I am trying to find rss links in a website. But my code returns img src and css links as well because it's src contains rss word.

This is my code:

```
import urllib2
import re

website = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.apple.com/rss")
html = website.read()
links = re.findall('"((http)s?://.*rss.*)"',html)
for link in links:
print link
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
## removing from top
html = re.sub('.*?<div id="container">', "", html)

## remove from bottom
html = re.sub('<div class="callout">.*', "", html)

## then match
links = re.findall('<li[^>]*>\s*<a href="(https?://[^"]*)"', html, re.IGNORECASE)
## you can push the text rss inside the pattern if you want
```

Comment: But what if the sites are not same? I am doing this operation for many webpages.

Comment: I do it manually. I don't know any better solution for this. But if you are lazy to do it manually, then you can parse all the href links from the page(rss & non-rss). And do a HEAD request to the link and examine server response. If it has 'Content-Type: application/xml' then get assured that its an RSS link. But this will be much slower, counts your bandwidth too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend parsing HTML with a regular expression.  There are better tools for finding links on web pages.  My favorite is [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#working-with-links).

```
import lxml.html
root = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
links = root.iterlinks()
links.next()
```

The above will allow you to iterate over each link.  You then need to infer whether the link refers to an RSS feed.  Here are some ways you might do this...

- Look for keywords related to RSS in the url
- Make a request and check the response type (`application/rss+xml`)

Without actually checking the server response, you won't know whether something is RSS.  A URL like `http://www.example.com/f` might be an RSS feed.  You can't know for sure until you check.